# Javascript if else function working only after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've checked other questions about the same effect but the ones I found haven't helped.
The javascript code works perfectly but not on first click. (When clicked the first time nothing happens but every next time all is well.) It is placed at the end of HTML's `<head>`  as

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#askLink").click(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display === "none") {
                document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the `askLink` is set up as

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="askLink">Ask</a>
</li>
```

Another hyperlink is set up pretty much the same way with a different function and isn't affected by such an issue.
What am I missing?

Comment: Here is your code working on first click: http://jsfiddle.net/gnubo7rw/ . Maybe there are some other issue in the rest of your code.

Comment: @kaperu not sure but Sudhir's idea works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using jQuery, you could simply do:

```
$(function () {
    $("#askLink").click(function () {
        var askArticle = $('#askArticle');

        //check if #askArticle is visible
        var isShown = askArticle.is(":visible");            
        askArticle.toggle(!isShown); //set to show or hide as per isShown
        $('#CONTENT').toggle(isShown);         
    });
});
```

and btw, your link `<a href="javascript:;" id="askLink">Ask</a>` will work without any change to it

Answer (score 3):

Remove the javascript from a href:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="askLink">Ask</a>
```

Should be this:

```
<a href="#" id="askLink">Ask</a>
```

Or, you may use '':

```
<a href="javascript:'';" id="askLink">Ask</a>
```

Also, try to use preventDefault():

```
$("#askLink").click(function (e) {
e.preventdefault();
```

Comment: thank you but removing `javascript:;` made the link refresh the page and changing it to `javascript:'';` made the click on it have no effect at all

Comment: @kaperu @C-link Nepal if I make `href="#"`, it still doesn't work on first click

Comment: try this :: $("#askLink")[0].click(function () {

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 'javascript:;' from the anchor to '#'

`<a href="#" id="askLink">Ask</a>`

And to prevent the page to be refreshed or go at the top use `preventDefault()` as such:

```
$("#askLink").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display === "none"){ 
    document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "none";
    }
  else{ 
    document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "block"; //Its block not "CD"
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't reload, doesn't load the function and changes the url to /#

Comment: Keep the `(function(){ /*the function*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

You should use on not click:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#askLink").on("click" , function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        if (document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display === "none") {
            document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('askArticle').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('CONTENT').style.display = "block";
        }
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#"></a>
```